# Concatenate parts of two or more webm video blobs

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webm, vp8

Is it possible to to concatenate parts of two or more video blobs encoded in webm format using just client side javascript?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the media source extension as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/

Both Firefox (partially), Opera Chrome already support this. IE11 only on Windows 8+.

Also, take a look at DASH (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) and HLS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)