# How to use "segments" mode at SourceBuffer of MediaSource to render same result at Chomium, Chorme and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, chromium, media-source

Reference to my original question: [How to use Blob URL, MediaSource or other methods to play concatenated Blobs of media fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217962/how-to-use-blob-url-mediasource-or-other-methods-to-play-concatenated-blobs-of)

In lieu of the potential for deprecation of the `"sequence"` mode for multiple tracks, which the current code is using for both Chromium and Firefox browsers my additional questions are:

1. Which adjustments need to be made in my `MediaSource` code to render the same result using both Chromium which Firefox browsers - currently renders as expected using `"segments"` `.mode`?
2. Or, is there a bug in the implementation of multitrack support using Chromium browsers when `SourceBuffer` `.mode` is set to `"segments"`?

---

### Background information

I have been able to record discrete media fragments using `MediaRecorder`, adding cues to the resulting `webm` file using [`ts-ebml`](https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml) and recording the discrete media fragments as a single media file using `MediaSource` with `.mode` of `SourceBuffer` set to `"sequence"` using both Chromium and Firefox browsers.

The Chromium issue at [Monitor and potentially deprecate support for multitrack SourceBuffer support of 'sequence' AppendMode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737757) discusses `"sequence"` mode is being considered for deprecation for multitrack `SourceBuffer` objects. When asked in the original references question regarding how to implement the code using `"segments"` `.mode` (default `AppendMode` of `SourceBuffer`) the response was essentially that `"segments"` mode also supports multitrack input at `SourceBuffer`.

However, when trying code with `.mode` of `SourceBuffer` set to `"segments"` Chromium 60 only plays approximately one second, the first buffer of multiple appended buffers, of an expected ten second playback of recorded media fragments having cues set at `webm` file which is converted to `ArrayBuffer` and passed to `.appendBuffer()`, while Firefox renders same result when `.mode` is set to either `"sequence"` and `"segments"`.

[Code](https://github.com/guest271314/recordMediaFragments) which renders expected result at both Chromium and Firefox. Note, Firefox does not play `.mp4` at `<video>` element if `multipleUrls` is tried, though Firefox does support playing `.mp4` at `MediaSource` when proper media codec is set.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- recordMediaFragments.js demo https://github.com/guest271314/recordMediaFragments/tree/master/demos 2017 guest271314 -->

<head>
  <!-- https://github.com/guest271314/recordMediaFragments/ts-ebml -->
</head>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="280" controls="true"></video>
  <script>
    (async() => {
      let request = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/recordMediaFragments/master/ts-ebml/ts-ebml-min.js");

      let blob = await request.blob();

      const script = document.createElement("script");

      document.head.appendChild(script);

      script.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      script.onload = () => {

        const tsebml = require("ts-ebml");

        const video = document.querySelector("video");

        const videoStream = document.createElement("video");

        // `MediaSource`
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        // for firefox 
        // see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259788
        const hasCaptureStream = HTMLMediaElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("captureStream");

        // handle firefox and chromium
        const captureStream = mediaElement =>
          !!mediaElement.mozCaptureStream 
          ? mediaElement.mozCaptureStream() 
          : mediaElement.captureStream();

        let currentFragmentURL, currentBlobURL, fragments;

        videoStream.width = video.width;

        videoStream.height = video.height;

        const mimeCodec = "video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus";
        // set to `.currentTime` of `videoStream` at `pause`
        // to set next media fragment starting `.currentTime`
        // if URL to be set at `.src` has same origin and pathname
        let cursor = 0;

        // https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657
        // https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
        const multipleUrls = [
          "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4#t=0,5",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=55,60",
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/master/media-source/mp4/test.mp4#t=0,5",
          "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4#t=0,5",
          "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4#t=0,5",
          "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4#t=0,6",
          "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/video/movie_300.mp4#t=30,36"
        ];

        const singleUrl = [
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=0,1",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=1,2",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=2,3",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=3,4",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=4,5",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=5,6",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=6,7",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=7,8",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=8,9",
          "https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4#t=9,10"
        ];

        const geckoUrl = [
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=10,11",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=11,12",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=12,13",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=13,14",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=14,15",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=15,16",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=16,17",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=17,18",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=18,19",
          "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=19,20"

        ];

        const mediaFragmentRecorder = async(urls) => {
          // `ts-ebml`
          const tsebmlTools = async() => ({
            decoder: new tsebml.Decoder(),
            encoder: new tsebml.Encoder(),
            reader: new tsebml.Reader(),
            tools: tsebml.tools
          });
          // create `ArrayBuffer` from `Blob`
          const readAsArrayBuffer = (blob) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const fr = new FileReader();
              fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
              fr.onloadend = () => {
                resolve(fr.result);
              };
              fr.onerror = (ev) => {
                reject(ev.error);
              };
            });
          }
          // `urls`: string or array of URLs
          // record each media fragment
          const recordMediaFragments = async(video, mimeCodec, decoder, encoder, reader, tools, ...urls) => {
            urls = [].concat(...urls);
            const media = [];
            for (let url of urls) {
              await new Promise(async(resolve) => {

                let mediaStream, recorder;

                videoStream.onprogress = e => {
                  videoStream.onprogress = null;
                  console.log("loading " + url)
                }

                videoStream.oncanplay = async(e) => {

                  videoStream.oncanplay = null;
                  videoStream.play();

                  mediaStream = captureStream(videoStream);
                  console.log(mediaStream);

                  recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                    mimeType: mimeCodec
                  });

                  recorder.ondataavailable = async(e) => {
                    // set metadata of recorded media fragment `Blob`
                    const mediaBlob = await setMediaMetadata(e.data);
                    // create `ArrayBuffer` of `Blob` of recorded media fragment
                    const mediaBuffer = await readAsArrayBuffer(mediaBlob);
                    const mediaDuration = videoStream.played.end(0) - videoStream.played.start(0);
                    const mediaFragmentId = currentFragmentURL || new URL(url);
                    const mediaFileName = mediaFragmentId.pathname.split("/").pop() + mediaFragmentId.hash;
                    const mediaFragmentType = "singleMediaFragment";
                    if (currentBlobURL) {
                      URL.revokeObjectURL(currentBlobURL);
                    }
                    media.push({
                      mediaBlob,
                      mediaBuffer,
                      mediaDuration,
                      mediaFragmentType,
                      mediaFileName
                    });
                    resolve();

                  }
                  recorder.start();
                }
                videoStream.onpause = e => {
                  videoStream.onpause = null;
                  cursor = videoStream.currentTime;
                  recorder.stop();
                  // stop `MediaStreamTrack`s
                  for (let track of mediaStream.getTracks()) {
                    track.stop();
                  }
                }
                currentFragmentURL = new URL(url);
                // for firefox to load cross origin media without silence 
                if (!hasCaptureStream) {
                  console.log(currentFragmentURL);
                  request = new Request(currentFragmentURL.href);
                  blob = await fetch(request).then(response => response.blob());
                  console.log(blob);
                  currentBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  // set next media fragment URL to `.currentTime` at `pause` event
                  // of previous media fragment if `url` has same `origin` and `pathname`
                  if (urls.indexOf(currentFragmentURL.href) > 0 
                  && new URL(urls[urls.indexOf(currentFragmentURL.href) - 1]).origin === currentFragmentURL.origin 
                  && new URL(urls[urls.indexOf(currentFragmentURL.href) - 1]).pathname === currentFragmentURL.pathname) {
                    if (cursor > 0) {
                      url = url = currentBlobURL + currentFragmentURL.hash.replace(/=\d+/, "=" + cursor);
                      console.log(url)
                    }
                  } else {
                    url = currentBlobURL + currentFragmentURL.hash;
                  }
                } else {
                  if (cursor > 0 
                  && new URL(urls[urls.indexOf(url) - 1]).origin === currentFragmentURL.origin 
                  && new URL(urls[urls.indexOf(currentFragmentURL.href) - 1]).pathname === currentFragmentURL.pathname) {
                    url = url.replace(/=\d+/, "=" + cursor);
                    console.log(url)
                  }
                }


                videoStream.src = url;
              }).catch(err => err)
            }
            return media
          }
          // set metadata of media `Blob`
          // see https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml/issues/14#issuecomment-325200151
          const setMediaMetadata = async(blob) =>
            tsebmlTools()
            .then(async({
              decoder,
              encoder,
              tools,
              reader
            }) => {

              let webM = new Blob([], {
                type: "video/webm"
              });

              webM = new Blob([webM, blob], {
                type: blob.type
              });

              const buf = await readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
              const elms = decoder.decode(buf);
              elms.forEach((elm) => {
                reader.read(elm);
              });

              reader.stop();

              const refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(reader.metadatas, reader.duration, reader.cues);

              const webMBuf = await readAsArrayBuffer(webM);

              const body = webMBuf.slice(reader.metadataSize);
              const refinedWebM = new Blob([refinedMetadataBuf, body], {
                type: webM.type
              });
              // close Blobs
              if (webM.close && blob.close) {
                webM.close();
                blob.close();
              }

              return refinedWebM;
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));


          let mediaTools = await tsebmlTools();

          const {
            decoder,
            encoder,
            reader,
            tools
          } = mediaTools;

          const mediaFragments = await recordMediaFragments(video, mimeCodec, decoder, encoder, reader, tools, urls);

          const recordedMedia = await new Promise((resolveAllMedia, rejectAllMedia) => {
            console.log(decoder, encoder, tools, reader, mediaFragments);

            let mediaStream, recorder;

            mediaSource.onsourceended = e => {
              console.log(video.buffered.start(0), video.buffered.end(0));
              video.currentTime = video.buffered.start(0);

              console.log(video.paused, video.readyState);

              video.ontimeupdate = e => {

                console.log(video.currentTime, mediaSource.duration);
                if (video.currentTime >= mediaSource.duration) {
                  video.ontimeupdate = null;
                  video.oncanplay = null;
                  video.onwaiting = null;
                  if (recorder.state === "recording") {
                    recorder.stop();
                  }
                  console.log(e, recorder);

                }
              }
            }
            video.onended = (e) => {
              video.onended = null;
              console.log(e, video.currentTime,
                mediaSource.duration);
            }
            video.oncanplay = e => {
              console.log(e, video.duration, video.buffered.end(0));
              video.play()
            }
            video.onwaiting = e => {
              console.log(e, video.currentTime);
            }
            // record `MediaSource` playback of recorded media fragments
            video.onplaying = async(e) => {
              console.log(e);
              video.onplaying = null;

              mediaStream = captureStream(video);
              if (!hasCaptureStream) {
                videoStream.srcObject = mediaStream;
                videoStream.play();
              }
              recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                mimeType: mimeCodec
              });
              console.log(recorder);

              recorder.ondataavailable = async(e) => {
                console.log(e);

                const mediaFragmentsRecording = {};

                mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaBlob = await setMediaMetadata(e.data);
                mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaBuffer = await readAsArrayBuffer(mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaBlob);
                mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaFileName = urls.map(url => {
                  const id = new URL(url);
                  return id.pathname.split("/").pop() + id.hash
                }).join("-");
                mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaFragmentType = "multipleMediaFragments";
                // `<video>` to play concatened media fragments
                // recorded from playback of `MediaSource`
                fragments = document.createElement("video");
                fragments.id = "fragments";
                fragments.width = video.width;
                fragments.height = video.height;
                fragments.controls = true;
                fragments.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                  fragments.onloadedmetadata = null;
                  mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaDuration = fragments.duration;
                  URL.revokeObjectURL(currentBlobURL);
                  // stop `MediaStreamTrack`s
                  for (let track of mediaStream.getTracks()) {
                    track.stop();
                  }
                  resolveAllMedia([
                    ...mediaFragments, mediaFragmentsRecording
                  ]);

                }
                currentBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(mediaFragmentsRecording.mediaBlob);
                fragments.src = currentBlobURL;
                document.body.appendChild(fragments);

              }

              recorder.start();
            }

            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

            mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);

            async function sourceOpen(e) {

              if (MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
                const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
                sourceBuffer.mode = "segments";
                for (let {
                    mediaBuffer,
                    mediaDuration
                  } of mediaFragments) {

                  await new Promise((resolveUpdatedMediaSource) => {

                    sourceBuffer.onupdateend = async(e) => {
                      sourceBuffer.onupdateend = null;
                      console.log(e, mediaDuration, mediaSource.duration
                      , video.paused, video.ended, video.currentTime
                      , "media source playing", video.readyState);

                      // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1400587
                      // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766002&q=label%3AMSEptsdtsCleanup
                      try {
                        sourceBuffer.timestampOffset += mediaDuration;
                        resolveUpdatedMediaSource();
                      } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        resolveUpdatedMediaSource();
                      }
                    }
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(mediaBuffer);
                  })
                }

                mediaSource.endOfStream()

              } else {
                console.warn(mimeCodec + " not supported");
              }
            };

          })

          return recordedMedia
        };

        mediaFragmentRecorder(geckoUrl)
          .then(recordedMediaFragments => {
            // do stuff with recorded media fragments
            console.log(recordedMediaFragments);
            const select = document.createElement("select");
            for (let {
                mediaFileName,
                mediaBlob,
                mediaFragmentType
              } of Object.values(recordedMediaFragments)) {
              const option = new Option(mediaFileName, URL.createObjectURL(mediaBlob));
              select.appendChild(option);
            }
            select.onchange = () => {
              document.getElementById("fragments").src = select.value;
            }
            video.parentNode.insertBefore(select, video);
            video.controls = true;
            video.currentTime = video.buffered.start(0);
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    })()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: stacksnippets apparently does not load `Blob URL`, the code at https://github.com/guest271314/recordMediaFragments/tree/master/demos can be used to reproduce both `"sequence"` and `"segments"` mode results

Comment: Is it possible to cut this large mass of JavaScript down to something a bit smaller that still reproduces the issue here?