# ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) support as of 2018

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

As a long time programmer just getting into JavaScript programming, I have the following questions that are still unclear despite having read many articles.

- Looking at the [ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) support by browsers](http://www.webbrowsercompatibility.com/es6/desktop/), I can see that the supporting level is much less than that of Node.js, so the question is,
- If both [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) and browsers are using the [modern V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/), why supporting level are so different?
- Looking at the [ES6 support in Node.js](http://node.green/), I can see really really few ES6 features are unsupported now. However, what exactly does the *supported* means in the chart? I.e.,
- Does it means even I write using the support ES6 features, I still need to [use the Babel compiler to compile ES6 code to ES5](https://www.codementor.io/iykyvic/writing-your-nodejs-apps-using-es6-6dh0edw2o) for Node.js to use it?
- For TypeScript ES6-style JavaScript code that runs for Node.js, they are still need to be [transpiled into an ES5 compatible form](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/es6-with-typescript/table-of-contents), despite that Node.js almost cover all ES6 featues, right? I.e.,

for the following code,

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name) { }
    move(meters) {
        console.log(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    move() {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(5);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    move() {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(45);
    }

var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python")
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino")

sam.move()
tom.move(34)
```

Does it need to be transpiled into an ES5 compatible form to runs with Node.js or not?

Finally, any online site that I can try playing with TypeScript/ES6 code like above?

- I copy it to my chrome console, and got an error that I don't understand - `Unexpected strict mode reserved word`, and
- I tried it on http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html, but the `console` output is not working there.

Please help. thx.

Comment: All browsers do not use the V8 engine

Comment: There are a bunch of syntax errors in your Snake class.

Comment: To increase the chances on an answer, please ask 1 question, not 5.

Comment: ***"supported"*** in the node.js ES6 chart means that you can that native ES6 feature without a transpiler.  You can just write that ES6 feature in Javascript and it will work.

Comment: TypeScript has to be transpiled into Javascript because no browser or node.js engine runs TypeScript directly.  When you transpile your TypeScript, you can choose what you want the target Javascript that it generates to be (ES5 or ES6).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I now get a sense now. However, @trincot, I'm not going to split this one into *five* different questions, as I think they are interrelated. I.e., comments so far are good enough for me. If I'm unclear on something, I'll ask in a different thread instead.

Comment: What are you trying to determine or achieve?

Comment: @guest271314, "*I have the following questions that are still unclear*", just want to clarify on them.

Comment: Bullet point 2 is false

Comment: "_All browsers do not use the V8 engine_". That is not helping. Chrome does, IIRC, but still, cannot comare to nodejs.

Comment: Well, you can scratch that off of the list. Nodejs is not a browser. You need to write the code and test the code in the environments that the code is going to be used in.

Comment: "_Bullet point 2 is false_", not helping either. What's the correct statement then?

Comment: Node runs on a server - it is configured to use the V8 JS engine by default. Web browsers run on  a client - they use a variety of different JS engines depending on the vendor which you can't change (e.g., Firefox uses SpiderMonkey, MS Edge uses Chakra). Thus, the support between them is different. The question really is "where is your code running?" Server side code in your Node app doesn't need to be transpiled if V8 supports your desired features. Client-side code should (probably) be transpiled to ensure it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Looking at the ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) support by browsers, I can see that the supporting level is much less than that of Node.js, so the question is,

Many different browsers and many different Javascript engines in them, each with their own level of ES6 support.  The latest version of node.js is generally pretty up-to-date on what the V8 engine supports.  Many browsers have longer release cycles and may not be as current, but each is different and has their own release strategy and level of ES6 support.

> If both Node.js and browsers are using the modern V8 engine, why supporting level are so different?

If you compare the latest release of node.js with the latest release of Chrome on Windows, you won't see much difference in support.  The ES6 support chart you're looking at seems old to me.  For example, Chrome has had support for the `Set` object for a long time, but your chart says `false`.

> Looking at the ES6 support in Node.js, I can see really really few ES6 features are unsupported now. However, what exactly does the supported means in the chart? I.e.,

Supported means you can use the feature directly without a transpiler, but how accurate that is depends upon the source of the document claiming it.  Some documents do extensive testing of all the various edge cases of a given feature. 
 Others just look for general implementation.  So if for example, you're looking at support for the `Set` object and it says "supported", then that is suppose to mean that you can just write plain Javascript that uses the `Set` object and it will just work.  How accurate that document is depends upon the source of their data and the thoroughness of their testing.

> Does it means even I write using the support ES6 features, I still need to use the Babel compiler to compile ES6 code to ES5 for Node.js to use it?

No.  In a Javascript engine that supports a given feature in ES6, you can write ES6 code for that feature and directly run it in that Javascript engine.  No transpiling is needed.

> For TypeScript ES6-style JavaScript code that runs for Node.js, they are still need to be transpiled into an ES5 compatible form, despite that Node.js almost cover all ES6 featues, right? I.e.,

The class definitions you show are plain ES6 code.  Those will work just fine as is in an ES6 capable Javascript engine.

If you write Typescript code, then you will have to transpile the TypeScript to Javascript because no Javascript engine (I know of) supports TypeScript directly.  When transpiling form TypeScript to Javascript, you can usually specify whether you want the transpiler to generate ES5 compatible code (which will run in an ES5 engine or an ES6 engine) or ES6 compatible code (which will only run in an ES6 engine) depending upon what your target environment is capable of.

> Does it need to be transpiled into an ES5 compatible form to runs with Node.js or not?

Your particular code appears to contain at least one TypeScript style variable declaration which would need to be transpiled.  The rest looks like plain ES6 Javascript which should work in any ES6 engine without transpiling.

When I remove the TypeScript, fix some syntax errors in your code and implement the `Animal` constructor properly, then this code works fine in node.js v8.8.1 (which is what I currently have installed) and in Chrome 63.0.3239.132, Edge 41.16299.15.0 and Firefox 57.0.4 all on Windows 10:

```js
    // Generic ES6 code

    class Animal {
        constructor(name) { 
            this.name = name;
        }
        move(meters) {
            console.log(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
        }
    }
    
    class Snake extends Animal {
        move() {
            console.log("Slithering...");
            super.move(5);
        }
    }
    
    class Horse extends Animal {
        move() {
            console.log("Galloping...");
            super.move(45);
        }
    }
    
    var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
    var tom = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");
    
    sam.move();
    tom.move(34);
```

You can run this snippet yourself in any browser you desired to see the results (assuming the browser is modern enough to support a stack overflow snipppet).  It works in all the current versions of browsers I have except IE 11.192.16299.0 (no surprise that IE doesn't support ES6).

> I copy it to my chrome console, and got an error that I don't understand - Unexpected strict mode reserved word,

This happened to me when I tried to run your code in node.js until I removed the TypeScript from it so that it was just plain ES6.  I think this particular error is caused by the `public` in this line:

```
constructor(public name) { }
```

since that is not part of the ES6 specification (it's apparently part of TypeScript).

> It seems that there's one question you're dying to ask, but haven't exactly articulated is: "How do you know whether you have to transpile or not?".

The answer is that you have to understand the cross between the target environments you wish to run in and the newest features you plan to use.  If you are writing server-side code that will only run in node.js, then it's a lot simpler.  Examine a comprehensive table such as http://node.green/, study what it says for the node.js version you plan to use and the feature in question.  If it indicates you should be able to use that feature, then write your code using that feature, write a test case for it and verify that both the code you wrote and the feature you are using both work.  Add that to your body of knowledge about what you can and can't use in that version of node.js.  You can then assume all future versions of node.js will also support that feature.

If you're writing code to run in a browser, life is much more complicated.  If you plan to support a lot of browsers and really don't want to worry about ES6 support at all, then just transpile to an ES5 target and go about your business.

If you want to use non-transpiled code, then you have a lot of testing to do in a lot of browsers.  You have to first specify exactly which versions of which browsers you are going to support and then you have to write your code and test cases and you have to test in every browser you plan to support.  There really is no shortcut.  When you find things that don't work, you'll have to either look for polyfills or work-arounds or stop using that ES6 feature.

Comment: "_It seems that there's one question you're dying to ask, but haven't exactly articulated_", OMG, YES! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Test the code in the environments that the code is going to be used in. Use the available means to implement the specific standard or specification within the environment that you are using the code at. Or try to create an approach yourself to resolve an issue that you encounter during development of your code while noting the progressions and persistent issue for others to be able to possibly address and resolve the issue, bug or requirement from their own perspective.

Simply due to the fact the a document states that the browser has implemented a specification or standard does not mean that the implementation is consistent with the specification, or implemented at all. The only way to verify whether a browser implements a standard is to test with code yourself. File issues and attempt to fix bugs yourself.

Browsers use different engines including [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko), [WebKit](https://webkit.org/), not [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8) alone; and can change over time in both name and implementations of specifications; see [Monitor and potentially deprecate support for multitrack SourceBuffer support of 'sequence' AppendMode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737757); [How to use "segments" mode at SourceBuffer of MediaSource to render same result at Chomium, Chorme and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379009/how-to-use-segments-mode-at-sourcebuffer-of-mediasource-to-render-same-result). There are many browsers. For example, [Lynx](https://lynx.browser.org/) does not use V8.

See [web platform tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests)

> The web-platform-tests Project is a W3C-coordinated attempt to build a
>   cross-browser testsuite for the Web-platform stack. Writing tests in a
>   way that allows them to be run in all browsers gives browser projects
>   confidence that they are shipping software that is compatible with
>   other implementations, and that later implementations will be
>   compatible with their implementations. This in turn gives Web
>   authors/developers confidence that they can actually rely on the Web
>   platform to deliver on the promise of working across browsers and
>   devices without needing extra layers of abstraction to paper over the
>   gaps left by specification editors and implementors.

For example, one test for [Web Speech API](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/issues/8795), where `volume` property is specified as capable of being set, though was not able to detect a change of audio output for either Chromium or Firefox when setting the `volume` property of `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` to different values within the specified ranges.

Specifications are a totally different regime than actual browser implementations. Specifications or standards can be and are written well in advance of actual browser implementation, if implemented at all. You can use [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify), or write the code yourself to use NodeJS modules or other non-native code in the browser.