# how to open html 5 video fullscreen if it was fullscreen before

Tags: javascript, video, fullscreen

I'm watching a series of videos on a website organised in a playlist. Each video is about 2 minutes long.

The website uses HTML 5 video player and it supports auto-play. That is each time a video ends, the next video is loaded and automatically played, which is great.

However, with Fullscreen, even if I fullscreened a video previously, when the next video loads in the playlist, the screen goes back to normal, and I have to click the fullscreen button again....

I've tried writing a simple javascript extension with Tampermonkey to load the video fullscreen automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function makefull() {
    var vid = $('video')[0]
    if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
      vid.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }

    //var vid = $('button.vjs-fullscreen-control').click();

  }

  makefull()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

It's extremely annoying to have to manually click fullscreen after each 2 min video. Is there a way I can achieve this in my own browser? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What is the expected result of using `setTimeout`? Programmatically executing `.click()` is not trusted, unless triggered within an event handler dispatched by user action within a narrow time frame, see [Trigger click on input=file on asynchronous ajax done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728705/trigger-click-on-input-file-on-asynchronous-ajax-done)

Comment: @guest271314 I just used setTimeout in order to wait for the video tag to appear on the page. Yes, so is there a workaround? I don't want to have to keep clicking all the time.

Comment: Why was `setTimeout()` removed from the question if that is the actual code used? What do you mean by _"appear on the page"_? Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate the issue with the code that you have tried?

Comment: @guest271314 setTimeout is completely irrelevant here. As I said, it was just a way to ensure the video element was present on the page. The question is about how to make the video open full screen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the list of URL's then you can create your own playlist. The code cannot be accurately tested within a cross-origin `<iframe>`, for example at [plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co). The code can be tested at `console` at this very `document`. To test the code, you can use the variable `urls` at [MediaFragmentRecorder](https://github.com/guest271314/MediaFragmentRecorder/blob/master/MediaFragmentRecorder.html) and substitute `"pause"` event for `"ended"` event at `.addEventListener()`.

If you have no control over the HTML or JavaScript used at the site not sure how to provide any code that will be able to solve the inquiry.

```
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.controls = true;
    video.autoplay = true;
    const urls = [
      {
        src: "/path/to/video/"
      }, {
        src: "/path/to/video/"
      }
    ];

    (async() => {

      try {
        video.requestFullscreen = video.requestFullscreen 
                            || video.mozRequestFullscreen 
                            || video.webkitRequestFullscreen;
        let fullScreen = await video.requestFullscreen().catch(e => {throw e});
        console.log(fullScreen);
      } catch (e) {
          console.error(e.message)
      }

      for (const {src} of urls) {                             
        await new Promise(resolve => {
          video.addEventListener("canplay", e => {
            video.load();
            video.play();
          }, {
            once: true
          });

          video.addEventListener("ended", resolve, {
            once: true
          });
          video.src = src;
        });

      }
    })();
```

Comment: @siamii See also [How to use Blob URL, MediaSource or other methods to play concatenated Blobs of media fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217962/how-to-use-blob-url-mediasource-or-other-methods-to-play-concatenated-blobs-of)

Comment: sounds reasonable. I think the best option is to download all the videos and just play them fullscreen offline. I have control with Tampermonkey and the site in question is https://www.coursera.org . So what this code does is create a new video player with playlist in fullscreen and play all the videos in the `urls` list?

Comment: @siamii _"So what this code does is create a new video player with playlist in fullscreen and play all the videos in the urls list? "_ Yes. There is no loop. Once the list is completely that is the completion of the program. A loop can also be included in the program, if necessary.