# I need to combine Multiple video streams and feed a video element in Javascript ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, react-hooks, mediastream

I have 2 videos that I want to be joined as one to have of faster loading experience on the client. That means having to load seperate video data and play them like a play list but with a smooth transition too.

I have two ways of doing it

**1. Load streams seperately, spliting them into chunks, comnbining them and making feeding them as source for the video Element.**

In experiment 1 I have a few issues.

i. Without the for looped fetch, I can correctly set a single stream to the source of my video BUT when using the loop to fetch each stream seperately, it does not work:
- I looked for a way to combine video streams and I found [How to use Blob URL, MediaSource or other methods to play concatenated Blobs of media fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217962/how-to-use-blob-url-mediasource-or-other-methods-to-play-concatenated-blobs-of). However it tackles editing one video - splitting one video and joining back also mentioning that you cant just seperate chunks and combine and expect it to play.

In my case its 2 different, complete videos(even duplicate video files but from different streams). It seems this route is an overkill for my problem. Is there a simpler way, perhaps a library than can help me join these streams and convert them to a blob?

Here is my attempt. Another confusion is the chunks array in my custom hook is still empty after the loop finishes running:
[Codesanbox Demo 1 - Streams](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cloud-9vbr3)

**2. use canvas to draw the videos one over the other in sequence**
I found a working solution and ported it to react. Here is my demo:[Codesandbox Demo 2 - Canvas](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-euler-2tdzs). The problem I have here is that this ONLY works on safari with a few issues. It does not work at all on other browsers.

[Here is the original working solution](https://github.com/totymedli/html5-video-playlist-prototype/blob/master/canvas-demo.html) BUT that same example does not work well when I replace video sources with my urls. Could it be because mine is not .mp4? Check it out here [Original Solution on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-meninsky-0bnyu).Same code, different source, it also shows me a `The index is not in the allowed range.` error..

What a I doing wrong in both cases?

I guess No 2 could be a seperate question but I am posting here under the same problem. Lemme know if I should post it seperately.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You basically want to play first video when it end the second play ?

Comment: Yes, but with a seemless transition. the second video should have already loaded before the first ends